# ESTA to USA. Step 6 of 7 won't complete

Tags: esta

I trying to complete my ESTA application, but I get to step 6 of 7 (before payment) and when I click NEXT, noting happens (it seems to load, but not getting further). Non of the form fields are incomplete, and all the info is correct. I have tried on several browsers and computers without getting to the payment form.

Have anyone experience this? Any clues on how to get to the payment step?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you are using the [genuine site](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/)? It ends with .gov. There are many scam sites.

Check carefully about from top to bottom about subtle error messages. Last time I had error on the address. The site has a strange validation, and it would not accept a valid address, so check in Google map (directly and other things at same address) on how to write in an alternate way the address.  As you see, there are some really annoying validation. Check also foreign characters, and formatting (e.g. if you did a copy paste).